# Index name for Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1 is installed on my machine and I want to install Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2.

Sitecore Commerce doesn't include any prefix/postfix with the index name like Sitecore 9.0 or other version does. (For example: XXX_web_index). Sitecore Commerce directly creates three indexes without any prefix/postfix (For example: CatalogItemsScope, CustomersScope and OrdersScope).

Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1 is already installed on my machine. So, the above-mentioned indexes are already created on my installed SOLR. Since I want to install Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 on this same machine, I must have to create these indexes with other names.

Configuration file "\Configuration\Commerce\Solr\sitecore-commerce-solr.json" have indexes information which gets created while installing Commerce.

[image]

I am pretty sure, if I change the index name here, indexes would be created with that name only. but will Sitecore Commerce point/use the changed indexes?

Comment: There is a "SearchIndexPrefix" parameter that you can use in your ps1 deploy script. Take a look on my ps1 script that I have used for installing Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 -> https://github.com/chorpo/SitecoreCommerce9Installation/blob/master/sxc9u2-My-Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1

Comment: Please split this question into two. Keep rhis one and ask only index part. Create similar second question where you ask for websites

Comment: Thanks Peter. I missed that configuration part. I got my answer. thanks again.

Comment: I have added an answer with further clarification

Comment: Please accept my answer if you are satisfied with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify "SearchIndexPrefix" parameter in your ps1 deploy script. This parameter is used to set prefix for index cores for indexes used by Commerce.

I am usually specifying it as name of my site instance to easily find it as it will correspend to my site name.

`SearchIndexPrefix = "$($SiteInstance)"`

You can find details of all parameters in installation guide -> http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Installation-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Installation_Guide(On-Prem).pdf

Take a look on my ps1 script that I have used for installing Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2. That could help you also to set remaining parameters -> https://github.com/chorpo/SitecoreCommerce9Installation/blob/master/sxc9u2-My-Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1